# How to install Gentoo with VirtualBox and use it as native OS later?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, gentoo

I'd like to try Gentoo (again...). I know that many steps require a lot of configuration and much more time. I'd like to do something else on computer during long waiting, because of that I would like to install it using VirtualBox and then move it to an partition and use it as normal OS.

Update:

I know how to `chroot` from live to HDD, "restore" GRUB bootloader. I need especially to know how to have my Gentoo installed to real HDD partition using VirtualBox.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you succeed in installing Gentoo with virtualbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a real disk, and not a "Virtual Disk" (aka .vdi for VirtualBox).

Note: on some systems the "vboxmanage" command is case sensitive and would be spelled `VBoxManage`.

`vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /my-vbox-real-disk.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/your_disk`

"filename" points to a "link" file that you will attach to the Virtual Guest. "rawdisk" is the physical disk you want to use, such as `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdc`.

Now the disk can be placed in a new machine (bare metal) after the Gentoo install is finished.

Comment: I would like to use partition instead of whole disk.

Comment: On the physical disk or in a virtual disk, do you know what you are asking? You aren't clear.

Comment: I want to install Gentoo with VirtualBox, but after installation I want to have it installed on certain physical partition. I don't care if I use virtual disk for installation or I install it directly on physical partition (not disk).

Answer (score 3):

Use Ubuntu installation LiveCD to install Gentoo. While you are installing, you can browse the web etc. That is how I used to do it. Most of the steps are the same as Gentoo.

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Gentoo-Linux-from-Ubuntu

Here is some guide lines for it, but I usually move on to Gentoo Handbook somewhere between step 10 and 15.

Comment: +1 Good idea. It provides alternative solution, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Well, you could install it in Virtualbox, then mount the .vdi image and do  cp -r /pathtovdi/* / . It should work.

Comment: Actually installing from ubuntu CDs are not recommended. Gentoo based CDs are better to prevent issues during installation (mainly uid mismatches that occur during stage extraction). Yes it can be done, but you'd have to use the alternate installation guide.